# How to select single row from resultset for one field?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

My select query is:

```
sql.select(COMPANY.NAME, COMPANY_CONTACT.NAME.as("CONTACT_INTERACTION"))
                .from(COMPANY)
                .join(COMPANY_CONTACT)
                    .on(COMPANY_CONTACT.COMPANY_ID.equal(COMPANY.ID))
.where(COMPANY.DELETED.equal(false));
```

' sql ' is of type **DSLContext**.

I'm trying to select just single **COMPANY_CONTACT.NAME** from all of them in the ResultSet.

Comment: have you tried .limit(1)?

Comment: @OleksandrRiznyk That limits both fields, but I need only the second one limited.

Comment: You mean you want to find one contact only per company? Which one? A random one? Or the one with the lowest ID?

Comment: @LukasEder The first one from 'PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY follow_up DESC'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I call a [TOP N per category query](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/22/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/), where `N = 1`.

#### Using SQL standard LATERAL

The simplest solution using SQL is by using the SQL standard `LATERAL` in PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, or `APPLY` in SQL Server, Oracle. Here's the PostgreSQL version:

```sql
SELECT
  c.name,
  cc.name AS contact_interaction
FROM company AS c
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT cc.name
  FROM company_contact cc
  WHERE cc.company_id = c.id
  ORDER BY cc.follow_up DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS cc 
WHERE NOT c.deleted
```

Or with jOOQ:

```java
sql.select(COMPANY.NAME, COMPANY_CONTACT.NAME.as("CONTACT_INTERACTION"))
   .from(COMPANY)
   .crossJoin(lateral(table(
        select(COMPANY_CONTACT.NAME)
       .from(COMPANY_CONTACT)
       .where(COMPANY_CONTACT.COMPANY_ID.eq(COMPANY.ID))
       .orderBy(COMPANY_CONTACT.FOLLOW_UP.desc())
       .limit(1)
   ).as(COMPANY_CONTACT)))
   .where(not(COMPANY.DELETED))
   .fetch();
```

#### Using PostgreSQL specific `DISTINCT ON`

In PostgreSQL, a TOP 1 per category query can be written also using `DISTINCT ON`, which is vendor specific for PostgreSQL, and also supported by jOOQ:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.company_id) c.name, cc.name AS contact_interaction
FROM company AS c
JOIN company_contact AS cc
ON cc.company_id = c.id
WHERE NOT c.deleted
ORDER BY c.company_id, cc.follow_up DESC
```

Or in jOOQ

```java
sql.selectDistinct(COMPANY.NAME, COMPANY_CONTACT.NAME.as("CONTACT_INTERACTION"))
   .on(COMPANY.COMPANY_ID)
   .from(COMPANY)
   .join(COMPANY_CONTACT)
   .on(COMPANY_CONTACT.COMPANY_ID.eq(COMPANY.ID))
   .where(not(COMPANY.DELETED))
   .orderBy(COMPANY.COMPANY_ID, COMPANY_CONTACT.FOLLOW_UP.desc())
   .fetch();
```

#### Using window functions

The same functionality can be implemented using window functions as well, but it will be less simple than the above solutions. If, however, you want the TOP 1 contact with ties in the result, then using the `RANK()` function is inevitable in PostgreSQL.

[A solution using window functions is also discussed in the previously linked blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/22/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/)

**Note**

All of the above jOOQ code assumes you have this static import in place:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```